# Reading Multiple CSV in R and Plotting With ggplot2

Tags: r, csv, plot, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to learn how to do some plotting with it. I managed to read in multiple csv files I have from some code analysis (7 of them), and melt them together as shown in the picture, but I'm not sure what I need to do to plot it correctly. The graph is giving me one combined line instead of multiple. How do I fix this? The line I ran to plot the graph is shown in the image, but in case it's too small I ran `ggplot(melted, aes(data_size, time_ms, colour=L1)) + geom_line()`

Thanks in advance!

[image: ggplot 2 result]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with R myself, but isn't melting your issue? That is combining the CSVs into a single data stream, hence the one graph.

Comment: add `group = L1` as aesthetic, or make it a discrete variable with `colour = as.factor(L1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the class of your L1 column, it's going to come back as "numeric". If you'd like to have all of the lines in the same space, `ggplot(melted, aes(data_size, time_ms)) + geom_line(aes(colour = factor(L1)))` will do the trick.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!